# Laravel - Disable session at subdomain

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How to disable session at some subdomain?
I need to have enabled session at main domain, and completly disabled sessions at API subdomain.

Comment: Check out this link: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-request-to-a-subdomain-is-causing-the-session-to-be-regenerated

Comment: I dont need to cross-domain cookie, i need to completly stop session generation for API subdomain.

Comment: You mean you don't want to have any session at all (no session cookie or anything) for the API subdomain? Also please specify the version of Laravel that you're using.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Why do I need to set a cookie for query the API. I think they should turn off at all.

Laravel 4.2

Answer (score 1):

In general you don't need to use cookies unless you want to persist data of some kind between requests or the cookies are the means by which some authorisation data is passed. So having the session enabled should not be any inconvenience to you if the cookies it generates are not used by your API (at most it creates a small overhead due to the extra cookie data, but that's about it).

That being said, the way you can disable session data from persisting across requests and disable using session cookies, is to use the `array` driver by setting it in `app/config/session.php`:

```php
return array(
    ...
    'driver' => 'array',
    ...
);
```